# how to Send proactive notifications to users with Microsoft bot framework in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, botframework, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Microsoft uses the following ways to Send proactive notifications(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python)

```
async def notify(req: Request) -> Response:  
    await _send_proactive_message()
    return Response(status=201, text="Proactive messages have been sent")

APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
APP.router.add_get("/api/notify", notify)
```

But what I want is to send notifications at the specific time. I thought creating task with asyncio may be the way to solve that. Is this the best way or I can use bot framework's some library to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bot Framework does not have builtin functionality to schedule notifications. You can create an asynchronous task inside your bot like you mentioned, or you can have an external scheduler access a special endpoint in your bot. How to expose such an endpoint can be seen in the proactive messaging sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/16.proactive-messages

Comment: I tried to create asynchronous task to send notification.But  web.run_app is high level function with get_event_loop inside itself. How to schedule notification without get_event_loop?

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? https://aiojobs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#integration-with-aiohttp-web